# Second Order Diff EQ

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$xy'' + (y')^2 - ({\frac yx})^2 = 0 $$
$$ y(1) = 2 $$and$$ y'(1) = -1$$

I'm sorry but I don't know what program everyone is using to write out the equations.

I'm not sure how to solve this. It somewhat reminds me of a Cauchy-Euler but it's not so I have no idea what to do. My professor didn't go over this either so a solution and explanation would probably be best. I can't provide any work for you all unfortunately.

Comment: Can you tell what exactly the task is for this initial value problem? Discuss the existence of a local solution, guess the behavior at $x=0$, find a large lower bound of how far the solution reaches to the right before blowing up,...?

Comment: My sheet just says”solve the following DEs”

Comment: You can write it as $0=(xy)''-2y'+(xy)'(y/x)'$, but at the moment I do not see any further simplifications.

Answer (score 2):

Consider that $xy''=(xy)''-2y'$ and complete the square, then apply a binomial formula
$$
0=(xy)''-1+(y'-1)^2-(y/x)^2=(xy'+y-x)'+(xy'-x-y)(xy'-x+y)/x^2
$$
This now is separable, so that
$$
xy'+y-x=C\exp(-y/x+\ln x)\implies y'+y/x-1=C\exp(-y/x)
$$
which is separable in $x$ and $y/x$. I'm not sure about symbolic integrability of
$$
\frac{(y/x)'}{1-2y/x+Ce^{-y/x}}=\frac1x.
$$